# Xamarin: CollectionView columns to trigger different actions

Tags: xamarin, collectionview

I have this in XAML:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Accepted}" 
                            SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="OnAcceptedSelected">
         <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding friendlyname}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         </CollectionView>
```

And this is the OnClick handler:

```
async void OnAcceptedSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            MyItem selectedMI = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as MyItem; 
            // do something
        }
```

I want to be able to do different things with selectedMI depending on what column the user clicked on, something like this:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Accepted}" 
                            SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="OnAcceptedSelected">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding friendlyname}"/>
                            <Label x:Name="Action_A" />
                            <Label x:Name="Action_B" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

so that I could do something like this:

```
async void OnAcceptedSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            MyItem selectedMI = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as MyItem;
            // if clicked on Action_A do something and
            // if clicked on Action_B do something else
        }
```

Xamarin doesn't seem to offer an obvious way to do that. Any ideas how to implement this functionality?
Thanks.

Comment: you would need to attach a gesture recognizer to each cell instead of using the CV Selection mechanism

Comment: But I am working with a collection of items.  How would a gesture recognizer know which of the items was selected?

Comment: each Label in each row would have a gesture recognizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding gesture to Label is a good choice.

I wrote a small example for your reference.

Two labels are added to each row of the CollectionView, and two events are respectively bound. Clicking on a different label will enter two different methods, and you can get the information of the label you clicked inside the method.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Accepted}" >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label  Text="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="tapCommand"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
                <Label  Text="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="blue" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="tapCommand1"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Here is the background code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Accepted { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        Accepted = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Accepted.Add("aaa");
        Accepted.Add("bbb");
        Accepted.Add("ccc");//Simulation data
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    private void tapCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)//event1
    {
        string res = (sender as Label).Text;
    }

    private void tapCommand1(object sender, EventArgs e)//event2
    {
        string res = (sender as Label).Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.